# Stubbing nested function calls in sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, stubbing

There are three seperate questions that are similar to this one but none of them resembles the case I have.

So I basically have a function which takes a function as a parameter

```
var myfunc ( func_outer ) {
    return func_outer().func_inner();
}
```

In my unit tests I want to be able to make a stub of a myfunc2. Basically I need to be able to stub a stub which is a nested stub. I currently use this kind of a manual stub but I would rather do it using sinon stubs if there is a way.

```
const func_outer = () => {
    return {
       func_inner: () => {return mockResponse;}
    }
};
```

Has anyone ever faced this situation. Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

From [sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.0/stubs/) you can check the returns section

> stub.returns(obj);
>     Makes the stub return the provided value.

You can try the following:

First you should make sure that you stub your inner function, and then make it return the value you want.

```
func_innerStub = sinon.stub().returns('mockResponse')
```

Then stub your outer function and make it return the object with your stubbed inner function.

```
func_outerStub = sinon.stub().returns({func_inner: func_innerStub})
```

You can follow this pattern with the *myfunc* function, as well and pass as a param the func_outerStub.